# How can I add my custom model function's value in my API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build my own poll app and the models have a lot of relation with each other and I need to count how many objects are in relation with some other objects so I need these custom function for it

Here's the model with the custom functions:

```
class Poll(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title

    @property
    def total_votes(self):

        votes = 0

        for o in self.option_set.all():

            votes = votes + o.how_much_vote

            return votes
        
    @property
    def users_involved(self):

        list = []

        for o in self.option_set.all():

            for v in o.vote:

                list.append(v.user)
        
        return list
            
    @property
    def users_involved(self):

        users = []

        for o in self.option_set.all():

            for v in o.who_voted:

                users.append(v)
        
        return users

    @property
    def total_votes_each_option(self):

        dct = {}

        for o in self.option_set.all():

            dct[o.title]= o.how_much_vote

        return dct
```

My question is how do you include all of those custom functions `total_votes`, `users_involved`, etc to my api? because right now my api looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Which is the best frontend framework?",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_available": true,
    "date_created": "2021-07-13T14:08:17.709054Z"
}
```

which is expected but I want to know how do I add those extra value to make it look like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Which is the best frontend framework?",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_available": true,
    "date_created": "2021-07-13T14:08:17.709054Z",
    "total_votes": "some number",
    "users_involved": [...users]
}
```

Edit: here's my serializer class

```
class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Poll
        fields = '__all__'
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show your serializer class, maybe: `PollSerializer`. You can use custom serializer [field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/), or [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: it's just a model serializers , I've edited the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way we can use SerializerMethodField

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_votes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    users_involved = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'is_active',
            'is_available',
            'date_created',

            'total_votes',
            'users_involved',
        )

    def get_total_votes(self, poll):
        return poll.total_votes

    def get_users_involved(self, poll)
        return poll.users_involved
```

Please note that `SerializerMethodField` is read_only, cannot for write.
Also make sure your custom model functions well for loop processing, using `select_related` or `prefetch_related`.

Comment: Another way you can use `field_name` from `source` like asnwer by Dushyant Deshwal.

Answer (score 0):

This one should be easy, you can add addition fields in Serializers by mentioning the field_name and its type before `class Meta:` something like this.

Model `Upload`

```
class Upload(models.Model):
.
.
total_files = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
.
.
def add(self):
        return (self.total_files + 2)
```

Serializer `FileSerializer`

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
#This is the line you need to add
    extra_add = serializers.IntegerField(source = 'add')
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields= ['id','name','uploaded','total_files','created_on','updated_on','extra_add']
```

Then mention your `extra_add` field name in `fields[..,..,'extra_add']`.
You can change the type of field while mentioning the field there`serializer.<field_type>(source='<method_name>')`.

Result of the Above field i added:
[image: ResultAPI Response]

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username')

class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_votes = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    users_involved = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = '__all__'

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        return queryset.prefetch_related('option_set')
```

Also note that you defined `users_involved` twice in your `Pool` class.

You can use `PoolSerializer.setup_eager_loading` function in your view/viewset for better db query performance but it's not necessary (I do it in `viewset.get_queryset` method like `self.queryset = self.serializer_class.setup_eager_loading(self.queryset)`.

Comment: Im not sure that `fields = __all__` will work with this custom fields but you need to test it. If it will not show up - you can try to define fields separatly `fields= ('id', 'title', 'total_votes', 'users_involved'...)`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just know it, i will test using this way for next case.